# javascript document.anchors.length returning 1 in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I am trying to run through a list of 6 anchors in a page using javascript to do some operations on them. However, the loop is not getting executed because anchors.length is return 1. The following is my code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
alert(document.anchors.length);
for (i = 0; i <= document.anchors.length; i++)
    {
        alert(document.anchors[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
<div>        
<ul>
<a id="sectionlinks" href="page1.html">link 1</a></li>
<a id="sectionlinks" href="page2.html">link 2</a></li>
<a id="sectionlinks" href="page3.html">link 3</a></li>
<a id="sectionlinks" href="page4.html">link 4</a></li>
<a id="sectionlinks" href="page5.html">link 5</a></li>
<a id="sectionlinks" href="page6.html">link 6</a></li>
<ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working fine in IE9. But in Firefox and Chrome, it is saying that the count is equal to 1. Would be great if someone can point me to what I have missed here.

As you might have guessed, I am a newbie to JS and am just learning it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least, you're learning the correct way, keep going!

What you've done wrong is that `document.anchors` refers to anchor links (old anchor links using the `name` attribute), not normal links. For example, the following is an anchor:

```
<a name="tab"></a>
```

And the following is a link:

```
<a href="/some/link"></a>
```

The links are in the `document.links` HTMLCollection, so you can use `document.links.length`.

If you want to get all the `<a>` elements, no matter what's in their attribute, you can use `document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' ).length`.

Answer (score 3):

See the note in [the MDN documentation](http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/anchor.html):

> For reasons of backwards compatibility, the returned set of anchors only contains those anchors created with the name attribute, not those created with the id attribute.

The property is designed to find anchors to link to, not from.

Use `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` to get a collection of `<a>` elements or [`document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.links) to get those and `<area>`s